# Как установить размер заголовка в DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Проблема в том, что при установке заголовка с помощью `getDialog().setTitle("Какой-то очень длинный заголовок который не влезает как надо ^_^ ");` если он слишком длинный, то не помещается полностью, а показывается только начало. Можно ли как-то назначить переход на новую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить в строку `"\n"` или `"/n"`. Вдруг поможет.

Comment: Так не пройдёт, потому что заголовки вставляются программно, нужно что-то что выполняется автоматически,я точно знаю что в ios есть механизм который позволяет задать переход на новую строку текста если он не вмещается в указанную область, есть ли что-то подобное в android?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?